# Can we run DDL scripts using FromSql in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

I know this is not what intended for, but just want to know FromSql whether we can use like this

```
_dbContext.Student.FromSql("ALTER TABLE Student ADD Grade varchar(max)")
```

I just want to push this once to my Azure SQL Test environment (still I am in development phase and dont have direct access to SQL editor), better i could have run Migrations, but some point i had messed with it, have to rely on something else. This is like a temporary fix.

Comment: yes you can run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSql("ALTER TABLE Student ADD Grade varchar(max)")
```

Comment: Seems like `ExecuteSql` is not available in efcore but it worked with `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`. Thanks a lot @bricelam